# how to retrieve a value from localStorage without using __zone_symbol__value property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing an isue with localStorage. When I store user information into localStorage I cannot retrieve it unless I use __zone_symbol__value property of the parsed value

The way I store into locaStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
```

The way I retrieve user information

```
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).__zone_symbol__value;
```

How to retrieve user information without using __zone_symbol__value ?

Comment: Check what you have in your `data` object before `setItem`, Do you have there a property called `__zone_symbol__value` ?

Comment: Why did you put -1. Yes I checked there is no property __zone_symbol__value. It is localStorage that add this property

Comment: What makes you think I put -1 ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution to get data from local storage. You can check your values by console.log().

Local storage store only string values so we need to parse string.

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = {
    'name' : 'Angular'
  } 

  constructor() {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.data));
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```